# Base image is not set when import csv using custom script magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am using custom script to import products in magento. product thumbnail or small image set using the code but the base image not set.
I am using the below code :

```
            $mediaArray = array(
                'image'       => $data['image'],
                'thumbnail'   => $data['image'],
                'small_image' => $data['image']
            );

            // Remove unset images, add image to gallery if exists
            $importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/product/';
            //echo $importDir;exit;
            foreach ( $mediaArray as $imageType => $fileName ) {
                $filePath = $importDir . $fileName;
                if ( file_exists($filePath) ) {
                    try {
                        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $imageType, false);
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Product does not have an image or the path is incorrect. Path was: {$filePath}<br/>";
                }
            }
```

What is the missing in the code. Can anyone suggest the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your code above the product save code :

```
$product->save();
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code for assign base image for a product if not assign.

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$c = 0;
foreach($products as $p){
    $pid = $p->getId();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);

    //get all images
    $mediaGallery = $product->getMediaGallery();

    //if($product->getImage() != "no_selection" ){   OR

    if($product->getImage()){
        continue;
    }else{
        if (isset($mediaGallery['images'])){
            //loop through the images
            foreach ($mediaGallery['images'] as $image){

                //set the first image as the base image
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('image'=>$image['file'],'small_image'=>$image['file'],'thumbnail'=>$image['file']), 0);

                $c++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
echo($c . " product(s) updated.");
```

Hope so it helps you.